# Get variance across slides of 3D array with numpy

Tags: arrays, numpy, 3d, variance

I have data shaped like (77,77,20) and I want to calculate the variance (using np.var) of the values accross the 20 slices. The idea is to return a 2D matrice shaped (77,77) containing the value of the cumulated var.

When I use the np.var() it doesn't seem to work and I can't find a suitable answer anywhere. Any idea ?

Comment: Use it along the last axis : `np.var(a,axis=-1)` or `np.var(a,axis=2)`?

Comment: It seems to work ! thanks, now I'll go and check on stackoverflow a way to save it

Comment: Just assign it to a new variable? `variances = np.var(a,axis=-1)`.